# What's a good way to sort a set of several correlated vectors?

Tags: sorting

Let's say I have a bunch of lists of real numbers which we'll call `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. Moreover, let's say all of these vectors are correlated, in the sense that `a[1] < a[2]` implies that there's a better-than-even chance that `b[1] < b[2]`. I want to sort each one of these lists individually, returning `a'`, `b'`,... with the same elements as `a`, `b`, ... but ordered. How can I sort all of these lists simultaneously in a way that takes advantage of these correlations to speed up the sorting? Does the answer to this change if the lists might be either correlated or anticorrelated? (We can rule out relationships like `b = x^2` -- let's say the relationship is monotonic, but not necessarily linear.)

Comment: I think you need to define the problem more precisely. If the lists are perfectly correlated, i.e., $a[i] < a[j]$ if and only if $b[i] < b[j]$ for every $i,j$. Then you just need to sort any one of the arrays. The other arrays will follow the same oredering.

Comment: As others have said, details matter here. But as a suggestion: Sort $a$ using your favourite method, also performing the same exchanges on $b$, then sort $b$ using any algorithm which performs well when the array is "almost" sorted. Insertion sort is an obvious choice, or Shell sort if that isn't quite good enough.

Comment: Are all lists the same length ?

Comment: If the relation is monotonic, the orders are the same !

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, the relationship is monotonic but probabilistic (not deterministic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of possible algorithms you could consider.  It's hard to say which will be optimal without more details and analysis.  Here are two ideas you could try out.

One approach is to sort the first list using a comparison-based sorting algorithm; and whenever you swap two items in the first list, swap the corresponding items in all subsequent lists.  Then, do the same on the second list.  If you use an [adaptive sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_sort), and if the correlation is high enough, then sorting each subsequent list might be a lot faster (because the previous sort got it into approximately sorted order).

Another option is to use a comparison-based sorting algorithm, where to compare item $i$ and item $j$, you count compare the $i$th item comes to the $j$th item in all list and take a majority vote.  You could pre-sort all lists using this comparison operator; then follow it up with an adaptive sorting algorithm on each list separately.